# Javascript not working with PHP echo statements

Tags: php, javascript

So, I'm using jQuery with PHP, and, I am echoing out a button:

```
echo '<input type="button" id="button" value="Info" style="float: right;"/>';
```

Pretty simple, I tried using "\" for the quotations, but, that didn't make any difference (for those who will point it out.

Anyway, the jQuery portion is pretty simple:

```
        $("#button").click(function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
```

Within the $(document).ready(function(){});

The echo is passed through an ajax call. If that makes any difference, and.

I do not get the alert. So if anyone can pinpoint the solution that would be great.

Comment: It doesn't matter who generated the code, but it matters what actually has been generated. Have you seen the final html in your browser?

Comment: debug: view source and fire bug

Comment: Does it work if you just make an html file with only those two elements. It's probably something else that's causing the problem. Also what browser did you test wtih?

Comment: <input type="button" id="button" value="Info" style="float: right; "/> - is what was generated according to firebug. There are multiple buttons mind you. Should it be kept as a class or id?

Comment: If you're loading the html from an ajax, you need to bind the event with `live` instead of `click` like @ken has done below in his answer.  The element doesn't exist when the event is bound, so it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have multiple buttons with the same id, that can definitely be a source of problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<input type="button" id="button" value="Info" style="float: right;"/>';

$("input#button").live('click',function() {
        alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Worked, thanks, now, I just need to figure out parent classes, and, get the parent ID. That is something I can figure out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"` instead of `'` for the quotes on the outside as PHP does not evaluate things inside single quotes.